# How to resolve JVM compatibility issues in Talend commandline

Tags: java, command-line, jvm, talend

Hi everyone I'm executing a job on Talend 6.3.1 on the commandline using this command :

```
executeJob job_name -i /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk/bin/java -jc DEV
```

and I always get the following error.

> Error Line: 8113 Detail Message: com.jcraft cannot be resolved to a
>   type

The job is using an SFTP component that calls the jsch-0.1.53.jar, the jar is present in the job but for some reason it doesn't seem to find it. The commandline log shows :

> !MESSAGE 2019-10-14 17:40:29,926 INFO 
>   org.talend.commons.exception.CommonExceptionHandler  - Missing jars:
>   jsch-0.1.53.jar

We also checked if the problem was the jdk version we're using but no results so far.

The job works perfectly fine when executed on the studio or even when built then executed on the server just not on the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to publish the job to Nexus Repository, and then retrieve the job on TAC from Nexus ? This way, the job is only compiled once in the studio, you won't have to use the commandline (as the job is already compiled). It is simpler than resolving libraries issues with the commandline.

Comment: thank you for your response but the this job has to be executed via the command line. Some of our jobs just have to go through the command line